# ngx-datatable, trigger column sort

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I'm having some problems trying to manuallky trigger sorting the rows in a ngx-datatable.
The scenario is that on small devices i'm moving some of the columns from the header to a ngx-datatable-row-detail, but when i try to invoke a customSort function, the rows in the ngx-datatable is not being sorted as i would expect.

The template looks like this:

```
<ngx-datatable #myTable [columnMode]="'flex'"
                   [rows]="_appointments"
                   [rowHeight]="'auto'"
                   [sorts]="listProps.currentSort"
                   (sort)="sorted($event)"
                   [columns]="_tableColumns">

        <ngx-datatable-row-detail [rowHeight]="'auto'" #myDetailRow>
            <ng-template let-row="row" let-expanded="expanded" ngx-datatable-row-detail-template>
                <div class="ngx-table-toogle hidden-md">
                    <div [class.visible-xs]="myCol.collapse_xs" [class.visible-sm]="myCol.collapse_sm" *ngFor="let myCol of _collapsedTableColumns">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" [class.sortable]="myCol.sortable" (click)="onCustomSort(myCol.prop,myCol.sortable)">
                            <div class="detail-row-header">
                                {{myCol.name}}
                                <span [class.sort-btn]="myCol.sortable" [class.sort-desc]="isSortedBy(myCol.prop,'desc')" [class.sort-asc]="isSortedBy(myCol.prop,'asc')"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                            <span class="detail-row-data">{{getVal(row,myCol.prop)}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
        </ngx-datatable-row-detail>
```

And the onCustomSort method like:

```
 onCustomSort(sortCol: string, sortable:boolean) {
        if (!sortable)
            return;

        let curdir = this.listProps.currentSort[0].dir === SortDirection.desc ? SortDirection.asc : SortDirection.desc;
        // Hmm, doesn't trigger a resorting of the table.
        this.listProps.currentSort = [{ prop: sortCol, dir: curdir }];
        this.table.sorts = this.listProps.currentSort;

    }
```

I would expect that modifying `this.listProps.currentSort` would trigger a resort of the table because it is bound to `[sorts]="listProps.currentSort"` but nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the solution was super simple, just had to add

```
this.table.onColumnSort({ sorts: this.listProps.currentSort });
```

to the onCustomSort method so it now looks like this:

```
onCustomSort(sortCol: string, sortable:boolean) {
    if (!sortable)
        return;

    let curdir = this.listProps.currentSort[0].dir === SortDirection.desc ? SortDirection.asc : SortDirection.desc;

    this.listProps.currentSort = [{ prop: sortCol, dir: curdir }];
    this.table.onColumnSort({ sorts: this.listProps.currentSort });

}
```

Comment: Are you able to provide a full code? I'm not understanding what is "this.table".

Comment: No, that piece of code is long gone - but this.table points to #myTable - the ngx-datatable instance.

Comment: No worries mate, I found a solution. Thank you for your replay

Comment: @MikNiller dude do you know how to fix the resize issue with misplaced columns?